# Get Json Array from PHP

Tags: android, json

I'm new in Android and JSON. Curently trying to fetch my data out from database. But it shows error. This is my logcat:

```
I/mytag: my json string{"success":1,"message":"Lecturer's Available","lecturer":[{"lecName":"Ariah","lecID":"1234","lecEmail":"ariah@gmail.com","lecPass":"123"}]}
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for lecName
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
W/System.err:     at com.example.foo.isfoo.lec_profile$LecturerProfile.doInBackground(lec_profile.java:99)
W/System.err:     at com.example.foo.isfoo.lec_profile$LecturerProfile.doInBackground(lec_profile.java:82)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
```

My question is how to get Json array? What I need to add for the error no value for lecName above? This is my java coding.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(PROFILE_URL);
                Log.i("mytag","my json string"+ json);
                lec_Name=json.getString(TAG_NAME);
                lec_ID=json.getString(TAG_ID);
                lec_Email=json.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                lec_Pass=json.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: show `getJSONFromUrl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this code.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                try {
                     json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(PROFILE_URL);

                     JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("lecturer");
                     for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

                       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       String lec_Name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_NAME);
                       String lec_ID = jsonObject.getString(TAG_ID);
                       String lec_Email = jsonObject.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                       String lec_Pass = jsonObject.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
                   }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code;

```
public static String[] ids;
public static String[] names;
public static String[] password;
public static String[] repassword;

  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strjson);
  JSONArray users = jsonObject.getJSONArray("lecturer");
  for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            ids[i] = jo.getString(TAG_NAME);
            names[i] = jo.getString(TAG_ID);
            password[i] = jo.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);

        }
```